# Logic of infinite statements

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

> Background: I have learned a little about mathematical logic and set theory from only Tao's *Analysis I*.

I am wondering the following question. Suppose we have a property $P$ pertaining to a set. And we know that $P(X) \wedge P(Y) \to P(X \cap Y)$. If we have infinitely many sets for which $P$ is always true, then can we say that for the intersection of all these sets $P$ is still true?

I think it is, but I don't know from what axioms can we conclude it. I think that if we can build a injection from a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ to the set containing those infinitely many sets, then we can use the mathematical induction axiom to prove this. However, we might not be able to build the injection. I don't know if my question is somehow related to mathematical logic. Do we conventionally admit that such a conclusion is true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general it is **not** true. For instance, the intersection of two open sets in a topological space is always open, but the intersection of infinitely many open sets need not be. An example in $\Bbb R$ is the family of open intervals $\left(-\frac1n,\frac1n\right)$ for $n\in\Bbb Z^+$: any intersection of finitely many is in fact one of these intervals, but the intersection of all of them is $\{0\}$, which is not open.

An example that needs no topology is obtained by letting $A_n=\Bbb N\setminus\{n\}$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$ and taking $P(A)$ to be the property that $\Bbb N\setminus A$ is finite. Clearly the intersection of any finite number of the sets $A_n$ has $P$, but the intersection of all of them is $\varnothing$, which does not.

What one **can** conclude is that for any **finite** family $\mathscr{F}$ of sets with property $P$, $\bigcap\mathscr{F}$ will have property $P$: this is a simple proof by induction on $|\mathscr{F}|$.

Comment: Another example: let $P(X)$ be the statement that $X$ is nonempty, and consider the family of sets $\big\{ [n,\infty)\colon n\in\Bbb Z \big\}$.